# I keep getting error with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Thank you guys for your answers.
I am now editing the question after considering all your solutions guys but I am still getting error. I am using support v4 now.

Here is the result. I keep getting the same error in the switch case block of code
[image]]

These are my current imports

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Here a new error I am getting after I changed the imports again guys
[image]

Comment: what your are extending in your activity and fragments ?

Comment: Please, learn to share your code as **text**, not as **images**!

Comment: @NullnVoid my Fragments extend to Fragment and my activity extend to AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Remove all Fragment's import from class and import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` again

Comment: I edited the question after bringing the changes you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the fragment that you are using is a of type `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`  and the method requires the fragment of type `android.app.Fragment` so you can go to your fragment remove the import statement of Fragment `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and add `import android.app.Fragment` it should work

the activity you are using the fragment in must extend the FragmentActivity and in place of getFragmentManger you should use getSuppotFragmentManager

```
public class YourActivity extends FragmentActivity{

}
```

and the fragments also must be of type `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited the question. I keep getting the same error after bringing the changes.

Comment: I guess my problem is solved :) but the fact is, I was using `getSupportFragmentManager` itself. Then I Chose to `getFragmentManager` instead and I changed all the imports to 
`
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
`
and all the error seems to have gone. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways we can use fragments

1. By importing fragment manager and fragments from support v4 library to support lower OS versions devices.
2. By importing it from standard android API

Here you are trying to use fragment from 1 and FragmentManager from other.

Hence you should use both from anyone I would suggest you to use support v4 library

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited the question after considering your changes.

Comment: Change import statement for Fragment as well :)

Comment: Yes I did change it to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` but I am getting the same problem.

Comment: What exactly the error says, can you please let me know about it

Comment: I re edited the question. I posted a link of the error I am getting after changing the imports to support v4.

Comment: You are using a library and I think that library has different names for Fragment and FragmentManager, just follow what error says

Comment: I would suggest you to forget everything and follow this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm to understand fragment concept

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys the problem is solved. I forgot to change the imports in the fragments to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. I only changed the imports in the main activity. That was so stupid of me that I could not recognize such a simple mistake.
Thank you for your help :)